# Error cuando ejecuto (PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'wkhtmltopdf')

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para dar mas contexto trato de hacer una prueba de un html a Pdf utilizado esa libreria pero me sale el error de los permisos y no se porque si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco mucho.

Probe añadiendo la viriable de entorno y no funciono y consulte google y naa y tampoco dando permisos especiales a la carpeta

Comment: intenta poner la librería en otro lado, Program Files necesita permisos de administrador. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda realizar el recorrido para ver la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, la verdad ya hice eso y sigue marcando el mismo error y también cambie las variables de entorno y nada.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el error _como texto, con formato_, además de resumir el error en el título. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].